# Can't get my access_token using Rails and the OAuth gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, twitter, oauth

I am developing my Rails 3 application that uses Twitter OAuth and I am getting troubles because apparently I can't get the access_token, after clicking 'Allow' and Twitter redirecting me back to my application  url, when I go to twitter.com/settings/connections I can't see my app there as authorized. I guess there is something wrong in my controller, I hope you can point them:

```
class OauthController < ApplicationController
  def start
    request_token = client.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => 'http://localhost:3000')
    session[:request_token] = request_token.token
    session[:request_token_secret] = request_token.secret
    redirect_to request_token.authorize_url
  end

  def callback
    @access_token = client.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])
    render :json => access_token_get('https://api.twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.json')
  end

  protected 

  def client
    @consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(
      'key','secret',
      :site => 'https://api.twitter.com',
      :authorize_url => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
      :access_token_url => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
    )
  end
end
```

Please help, tell me where is my mistake, thanks for the attention!

Rodrigo Alves Vieira.

Comment: actually, theres is a 'def start; request_token = client.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => 'http://localhost:3000')'
the markup hid the code and I couldn't fix :-p

Comment: this might be a dumb question, but have you registered the app on twitter?

Comment: Yes, I did. That's what makes the problem more weird :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what part of your code isn't working, probably something to do with the access_token_get method, but I'll show you how I did it--maybe it'll help..

after the line where you initialize @access_token, I do something like this:

```
@response = client.request(:get, "/account/verify_credentials.json", @access_token, { :scheme => :query_string })
case @response
when Net::HTTPSuccess
  user_info = JSON.parse(@response.body)
  unless user_info['screen_name']
    # authentication failed, error handling
  end
  # We have an authorized user, save the information to the database using @access_token.token and @acess_token.secret
else
  # error handling
end
```

(oh, and i was using the json gem, so make sure to `gem install json` and `require 'json'` at the top)

Hope that helps!